# Node MQTT.js problems with RabbitMQ

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, mqtt

Can't connect to my RabbitMQ server (MQTT adapter enabled) with node.js mqtt client. Is there a compatibility issue between these?

I can connect to the queue using bluerhinos MQTT PHP library, so I know the queue names and host name etc are correct, and that messages are being retrieved correctly

Node.js app

```
var mqtt = require('mqtt');

var mqttClient = mqtt.connect('mqtt://rabbit:1883');

mqttClient.on('connect', function() {
   console.log("connected");
});

mqttClient.publish('queue', 'message');
```

PHP

```
require("vendor/bluerhinos/phpmqtt/phpMQTT.php");

$mqtt = new phpMQTT("rabbit", 1883, "clientId"); 
if ($mqtt->connect()) {
    $mqtt->publish("queue","Hello World! at ".date("r"),1);
    $mqtt->close();
}
```

MQTT.js generates a random client id by default, so its nothing to do with the client id not being set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are connecting to a broker that supports only MQTT 3.1 (not 3.1.1 compliant), you should pass these additional options:

```
{
    protocolId: 'MQIsdp',
    protocolVersion: 3
}
```

**This is confirmed on RabbitMQ 3.2.4**.... and on Mosquitto < 1.3. Mosquitto version 1.3 and 1.4 works fine without those.

Answer (score 1):

The NodeJS code will be asynchronous so it is possible you are calling publish before the connection has completed. Try this to make sure it waits before trying to publish:

```
var mqtt = require('mqtt');

var mqttClient = mqtt.connect('mqtt://rabbit:1883');

mqttClient.on('connect', function() {
   console.log("connected");
   mqttClient.publish('queue', 'message');
});
```

Comment: Still no dice :/ . It's something to do with the connection. Blue rhinos uses fsockopen, I looked through the repo. Is this different from the sock connection that MQTT.js uses? I'm not familiar with sockets at all, the only messaging I'd done between machines was REST http requests.

Comment: Do you even see the connected message?

Comment: Can we assume that you have checked all the obvious things like netstat -tap | grep 1883 on the rabbit server?  Firewall on rabbit server configured to accept tcp 1883?